# Ошибка в FireFox

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.querySelector('.game_area').addEventListener('click' , function() {
    var x = event.target;
})
```

данный кусок кода выдает ошибку в firefox, хотелось бы понять в чем проблема
ошибка ReferenceError: event is not defined
[Весь код находится тут](https://github.com/TigranVardanyan/project_PurblePairs)

Comment: какую ошибку выдаёт, добавьте в вопрос

Comment: document.querySelector('.game_area').addEventListener('click' , function() {
    var x = event.target;
}); скобку забыли

Comment: скобку тут забыл, но проблема не в этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтоб обратиться к event, надо его передать в функцию.

```js
document.querySelector('.game_area').addEventListener('click' , function(event) {
    var x = event.target;
  console.log(x)
})
```

```html
<button class='game_area'>Button</button>
```

Comment: спасибо сработало, а почему в chrome можно и без этого?

Comment: Потому что chrome определяет event по дефолту, а firefox нет. Это можно проверить если попробуете обратиться к event в этих браузерах.